# Remove Braces from Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get each individual array value as a string. But I end up with braces in the string.
Like `["testusername1@xyz.com"]` instead I would need the output to be `"testusername1@xyz.com"`.

Example

```
user_emails = ['testuser1@xyz.com', 'testuser2@xyz.com', 'testuser3@xyz.com']
```

Expected output should be like

```
testuser1@xyz.com
testuser2@xyz.com
testuser3@xyz.com
```

Here is the code in ruby

```
user_emails.each do |user_email|
  puts user_email
end
```

I tried using

```
user_email.shift.strip
```

and even tried the following:

```
user_email.to_s
```

How can I extract the value alone?

Comment: try user_email[0] and see what you get? what is user_emails, just a plain array?

Comment: In essence, user_email is still an array somehow, so you want to get the first element or [0]

Comment: This question is incomplete. What's the type of `user_emails`? Is it an array of strings or an array of arrays of strings? If `user_email.shift.strip` is not working, I would think that the contents `user_emails` are not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on @Taoufik's answer, I anticipate that the contents of `user_emails` are actually strings. You can extract the desired substring as follows:

```
puts user_email[2...-2]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
user_emails.each do |user_email|
  p user_email
end
```

simple use p instead .puts